# Qt QGeoCoordinate adapt as boost::geometry point

Tags: c++, qt, boost, boost-geometry, qtlocation

Is it possible to adapt `QGeoCoordinate` as `boost::geometry` point type? `QGeoCoordinate` only has getter and setter methods for lat/lon - no public access to fields.

Comment: what do you mean by "adapt"?

Comment: Something like that: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/examples/example__adapting_a_legacy_geometry_object_model.html